# Send apport reports to private server instead of Canonical

Tags: apport

Is there a way for me to automate crash reports to a private server? I would like apport reports to be sent to http://example.com, not Canonical. I'm not sure if this has been already done or is a feature inside of apport. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the whoopsie service, not the apport application.

Simply edit `/lib/systemd/system/whoopsie.service` to point to your own server instead of daisy.ubuntu.com.

The basic process of crash reporting is:

1. Apport detects a crash and generates a .crash file. Then apport triggers whoopsie.
2. Whoopsie sends the .crash file to daisy.
3. Daisy sanitizes the crash file, files the bug report (if new), and aggregates the errors for http://errors.ubuntu.com

Um, do be aware that we cannot fix bugs and crashes that do not get reported to us.

Comment: This, and to add to that: crash reports are at /var/crash/ so can be sent anywhere regardless of whoopsie with a script that mails or rcp's them to another server.

Comment: Albeit, much easier than configuring apport and creating a server atm. Thanks.